# Angular clarity datagrid export filtered data to excel

Tags: html, angular, typescript, vmware-clarity

I want to export filtered/sorted data(or whatever other actions applied to the table, ie: hide specific column) instead of exporting all the data. Is there a way to do it? I am fairly new to angular, if you could use simple language to explain that'll be great!

Below are my codes

excel.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';


const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExcelService {

  constructor() { }

  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void { 
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);  
    delete (worksheet[1])
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };  
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });  
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);  
  }  
  private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {  
     const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: EXCEL_TYPE});  
     FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);  
  }

}
```

table.component.ts:

```
showTCExportMenu=false
  showTEExportMenu=false
  exportAsXLSX(data, name, reimport=false):void {
    let table = data

    reimport? null: table.forEach(
                    table => { table.justification? table.justification = table.justification.replace(/<\/?(?!a)\w*\b[^>]*>/ig, ''): null,
                              table.evidence?  table.evidence = table.evidence.replace(/<\/?(?!a)\w*\b[^>]*>/ig, ''): null,
                              delete table.id, delete table.log
                              })


    // execu ? this.getTestExecu(this.uuid): this.getTestCat(this.uuid)

    this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(table, name);
    this.showTCExportMenu=false
    this.showTEExportMenu=false
  }
```

table.component.html:

```
<div>
  <clr-datagrid  [(clrDgSelected)]="selected">
    <clr-dg-column
      *ngFor="let column of columns"
      [clrDgField]="getStringKey(column.key)">
      <ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden: false}">
        {{column.title}}
      </ng-container>
      <clr-dg-filter
        *ngIf="column?.filter"
        [clrDgFilter]="getFilter(column)">
        <ng-container filterHost></ng-container>
      </clr-dg-filter>

    </clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-row
      *clrDgItems="let item of records"
      [clrDgItem]="item">
      <clr-dg-cell
        *ngFor="let column of columns"
        [innerHTML]="renderValue(column, item)">
      </clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-row-detail
        [innerHTML]="expandRowRender && expandRowRender(item)"
        *clrIfExpanded>
      </clr-dg-row-detail>
    </clr-dg-row>

    <clr-dg-footer>
      <button class="btn" (click)="exportAsXLSX(tableData, 'example', true)">Export to excel</button>
      <clr-dg-pagination #pagination >
        <clr-dg-page-size [clrPageSizeOptions]="[5,10,20,30, 50, 100]">Users per page</clr-dg-page-size>
        {{pagination.firstItem + 1}} - {{pagination.lastItem + 1}}
        of {{pagination.totalItems}} records
      </clr-dg-pagination>
    </clr-dg-footer>
  </clr-datagrid>
</div>
```

here is where I get my data from api, catone.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TableColumns, TableData} from "../tableone/tableone.types";
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';
import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {ClrDatagridFilterInterface} from "@clr/angular";
import {AgefilterComponent} from "../agefilter/agefilter.component";
import {DatefilterComponent} from "../datefilter/datefilter.component";


interface InventoryData {
  test_name: any;
  description: any;
  status: string;
  test_level: string;
  test_category: string;
  test_type: string;
  test_approach: string;
  test_applicability: string;
  requirement_accountability: string;
  test_plan_accountability: string;
  trigger_type: string;
  applicable_metadata_statuses: string;
  assessment_level_targeted: string;
  comp_control_flag: string;
  testing_platform: string;
  effective_date: Date;
  test_retired_date: Date;
  metric_inclusion: string;
  policy_requirement: string
}



export  class AgeFilter implements ClrDatagridFilterInterface<InventoryData> {
  changes = new Subject<any>();
  public minAge!: number;
  public  maxAge!: number;
  accepts(person: InventoryData): boolean {
    return true
  }

  isActive(): boolean {
    return false
  }

}

export class BirthdayFilter implements ClrDatagridFilterInterface<InventoryData> {
  changes = new Subject<any>;
  value = '';
  accepts(item: InventoryData): boolean {
    return true
  }

  isActive(): boolean {
    return false
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'catone',
  templateUrl: './catone.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catone.component.scss']
})
export class CatoneComponent implements OnInit {
  columns: TableColumns<InventoryData> = [

    {
      title: 'Test_name',
      key: 'test_name'
    },
    {
      title: 'Description',
      key: 'description'
    },
    {
      title: 'Status',
      key: 'status'
    },
    {
      title: 'Test_level',
      key: 'test_level'
    },
    {
      title: 'Test_category',
      key: 'test_category'
    },
    {
      title: 'Test_type',
      key: 'test_type',
    },
    {
      title: 'Test_approach',
      key: 'test_approach',
    },
    {
      title: 'Test_applicability',
      key: 'test_applicability',
    },
    {
      title: 'Requirement_accountability',
      key: 'requirement_accountability',
    },
    {
      title: 'Test_plan_accountability',
      key: 'test_plan_accountability',
    },
    {
      title: 'Trigger_type',
      key: 'trigger_type',
    },
    {
      title: 'Applicable_metadata_statuses',
      key: 'applicable_metadata_statuses',
    },
    {
      title: 'Assessment_level_targeted',
      key: 'assessment_level_targeted',
    },
    {
      title: 'Comp_control_flag',
      key: 'comp_control_flag',
    },
    {
      title: 'Testing_platform',
      key: 'testing_platform',
    },
    {
      title: 'Effective_date',
      key: 'effective_date',
    },
    {
      title: 'Test_retired_date',
      key: 'test_retired_date',
    },
    {
      title: 'Metric_inclusion',
      key: 'metric_inclusion',
    },
    {
      title: 'Policy_requirement',
      key: 'policy_requirement',
    },

  ];
  tableData: TableData<InventoryData> | Observable<TableData<InventoryData>> = [];
  page = 1;
  pageSize = 10;
  total = 1000;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  renderExpand(p: InventoryData) {
    return `
      <pre>${'test name: ' + p.test_name}</pre>
    `
  }

  handlePageChange(page: number) {
    this.page = page;
    this.requestApi();
  }

  requestApi() {
    this.httpClient.get<InventoryData[]>(`myapi`)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.tableData = data
      })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.requestApi();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

without any exernal library you can use this function note that rows (in the class CSVargs) is the data to download so if you pass sorted rows or/and specific length's row should work

```
 export interface CSVargs<T> { // you can make change T by any
  rows: T[];
  keys: string[];
  titles: string[];
  filename?: string;
  columnDelimiter?: string;
  lineDelimiter?: string;
}
export function downloadCSV(args: CSVargs) {
  args.filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';
  args.columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ';';
  args.lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

  let csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args);
  if (csv == null) { return; }

  if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
    const bom = '\uFEFF';
    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + bom + csv;
  }
  const data = encodeURI(csv);

  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', data);
  link.setAttribute('download', args.filename);
  link.click();
}

function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args: CSVargs) {
  if (!args.rows || !args.rows.length) {
    return;
  }
  if (!args.keys || !args.keys.length) {
    args.keys = Object.keys(args.rows[0]);
  }
  if (!args.titles || !args.titles.length) {
    args.titles = args.keys;
  }
  let result = '';
  result += '"' + args.titles.join('"' + args.columnDelimiter + '"') + '"';
  result += args.lineDelimiter;

  args.rows.forEach(item => {
    let ctr = 0;
    args.keys.forEach(key => {
      if (ctr > 0) {
        result += args.columnDelimiter;
      }
      const value = (item && !item[key]) ? item[key] : ''; // is better to check item not undefined not null not empty (create a function to check is not blanc)
      result += '"' + value + '"';
      ctr++;
    });
    result += args.lineDelimiter;
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: should I replace what I have in service.component.ts with this?

Comment: yep! you can create a service for that and change   this line     <button class="btn" (click)="exportAsXLSX(tableData, 'example', true)">Export to excel</button>

Comment: i'm getting  this error TS2345: Argument of type 'TableData<any> | Observable<TableData<any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CSVargs<TableData<any>>'.

Comment: just use any[] instead of TableData<any>

Comment: I used 'CSVargs<any[]>' but still getting the same error.